# Laravel - insertGetId displaying Parameter mismatch error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help out with an error im getting.

I have the following code:

```
$suburbInsert = array();
$suburbInsert[] = array(

    'name' => $postalCode . ' ' . $suburbName,
    'suburb_name' => $suburbName,
    'pcode' => $postalCode

);

$suburbID = DB::table('suburbs')->insertGetId( $suburbInsert );
```

When i run it though, iam getting the following error

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array","file":"\/var\/www\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Support\/helpers.php","line":990}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `$suburbInsert` as an array of arrays.

Instead of:

```
$suburbInsert = array();
$suburbInsert[] = array(
    ...
);
```

Just do:

```
$suburbInsert = array(
    ...
);
```